Debugging a memory leak showing the leak is within a core Apple framework
I'm having an issue with my swiftui macOS application where it is continually consuming more memory over time and after a couple of hours will grind to a halt. I've watched a few videos now on how to use Xcode Memory Graph and Instruments to identify the source of a leak (I assume it is a leak). These videos all provide very obvious issues as examples but mine seems more elusive and I don't know how to identify which part of my code is the cause of the issue.
After running instruments I see the following but the leaked objects are not always consistent:

Xcode Memory Graph shows NSSet as the culprit which is shown under CoreFoundation (not my App). I really am a beginner here and because it's not showing me somewhere in my app that I can go and investigate I'm really stuck.
EDIT: I think my avplayer is somehow related se my other post
EDIT2: Further investigations I have determined that memory usage increases without constraint when I start playback of an AVPlayer. Here is the annotated memory profile:

Code from AVPlayer:
struct VideoPlayerView: NSViewRepresentable {
@Environment(GlobalTimelineModel.self) var globalTimelineModel

var playerView: AVPlayerView
var player: AVPlayer
@Binding var currentPlayerTime: CMTime
@Binding var isPlaying: Bool

@Binding var loopStart: Double
@Binding var loopEnd: Double
@Binding var shouldLoop: Bool

@Binding var isScrubbing: Bool

@State var shouldResumePlayback: Bool = false /// set to true when playback is paused from scrubbing

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
}


func makeNSView(context: Context) -> AVPlayerView {
    playerView.player = player
    playerView.controlsStyle = .none
    playerView.player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: globalTimelineModel.videoAVPlayerItem)
    playerView.player?.isMuted = true
    
    context.coordinator.onTimeUpdate = { time in
        currentPlayerTime = time
    }
    
    return playerView
}

func updateNSView(_ nsView: AVPlayerView, context: Context) {
    if nsView.player != player{
        nsView.player = player
    }
    
    if isPlaying{
        player.playImmediately(atRate: 1.0)
        
        // play again from the begining if we have reached the end
        if let playerCurrentTime = nsView.player?.currentTime().seconds, let playerDuration = nsView.player?.currentItem?.duration.seconds{
            
            if playerCurrentTime >= playerDuration{
                player.seek(to: .zero, toleranceBefore: .zero, toleranceAfter: .zero)
            }
        }
        
      
    }
    else{
        if player.rate != 0{
            player.pause()
        }
    }

}

func updatePlaybackPosition(player: AVPlayer){
    player.seek(to: currentPlayerTime, toleranceBefore: .zero, toleranceAfter: .zero)
}

func isWithinThreshold(value1: Double, value2: Double, threshold: Double) -> Bool {
    return abs(value1 - value2) <= threshold
}




class Coordinator {
        private var timeObserverToken: Any?
        private weak var player: AVPlayer? // Make player reference weak
        var onTimeUpdate: ((CMTime) -> Void)?
        
        init(_ parent: VideoPlayerView) {
            print("init Coordinator for player")
            self.player = parent.player // Store weak reference to player
            addPeriodicTimeObserver()
        }
        
        private func addPeriodicTimeObserver() {
            guard let player = player else { return }
            let interval = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 24)
            timeObserverToken = player.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: interval,
                                                      queue: .main) { [weak self] time in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                self.onTimeUpdate?(time)
            }
        }
        
        private func removePeriodicTimeObserver() {
            guard let timeObserverToken = timeObserverToken,
                  let player = player else { return }
            player.removeTimeObserver(timeObserverToken)
            self.timeObserverToken = nil
        }
        
        deinit {
            print("Coordinator deinit")
            removePeriodicTimeObserver()
        }
    }

}


It's almost certainly not an issue with NSSet. Without seeing any of your code it's almost impossible to help. Does this happen when you navigate to specific Views? Is it repeated calls to a function? Try and narrow down which piece of code logic causes the leak.

Check you aren’t initing any objects in SwiftUI except for ones wrapped in @StateObject.

I suspect the issue is in your code but it's hard to understand why. Could you show us the UI code where you interact with given AV frameworks? SwiftUI when misapplied tends to recreate certain resources on every UI change.

Thanks everyone. I haven’t necessarily narrowed down the actual cause of the leak but have identified that when I play my avplayer is when the memory increases. See my other post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79246272/swift-6-avplayer-with-addperiodictimeobserver-memory-leak

@tospig - I have updated my post with code and more details. Thanks

If you comment the context.coordinator.onTimeUpdate = {}  line? Also, when I try to debug these leaks, I'll start by the deinit. For instance, does print("Coordinator deinit") stop the leaks? Then, I'll check all (NS)Timers, check the closures with possible missing [weak self], etc. There is no "global easy solution", it's digging work...

commenting context.coordinator.onTimeUpdate = {} appears to remove the leak, but also means I'm not updating my UI with the current time of the player. Have I implemented the ui update incorrectly?

Try with a weak self: context.coordinator.onTimeUpdate = { [weak self] time in self?.currentPlayerTime = time }

'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not 'VideoPlayerView'

Oh, indeed, it's a struct, not a class.
