Swift 6 AVPlayer with addPeriodicTimeObserver = memory leak?
My app has a an AVPlayer with a periodic time observer (code below). I have adopted apples approach from here. Interestingly now that I have enabled 'complete' concurrency checking I see a warning on my player.addPeriodicTimeObserver.
If I make the containing class @Sendable I get the error below.

My app currently has a serious memory leak (see my related post here) and I'm now wondering if this has something to do with it as memory increases hugely when playback occurs.

private func addPeriodicTimeObserver() {
            guard let player = player else { return }
            let interval = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 24)
            timeObserverToken = player.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: interval,
                                                      queue: .main) { [weak self] time in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                self.onTimeUpdate?(time)
            }
        }


Can you edit the question to attach the code instead of images? Btw, these warnings are about data race, not leak as your thought.

I think you used an apple example from the pre-async era. So in your case it seems like you should use smth like AsyncStream https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/asyncstream
